# Wie kann man “hoher Standard” in einem Weilsatz benutzen?

Tags: grammatical-case, compound-adjective

Wie kann man in einem Konjunktivsatz mit kausalem Bindewort (*weil*) ein Adjektiv wie "Standard" beziehungsweise "hoher Standard“ benutzen!?

Bitte geben Sie ein Beispiel an.

Comment: Down voter, would mind to explain the reason for down vote?

Comment: We hardly get explanations for that.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but here's my guess on that: Looks like you're asking for a translation request or for proof reading. Both are off-topic here.

Comment: Yeah, and there are even *–censored–* who downvote valid answers based on their distorted views of reality.

Comment: That's a reason to vote to close, not to downvote

Comment: @Janka Unfortunately yes. False-down-votes on questions are even higher since there is no penalty for downvoter, this is sad. At least in answer downvoting they get a minus one! Thanks for your answer by the way!

Comment: @Robert looks like I should have deleted the example in the body of my question so it wouldn’t be mis interpreted as proof-reading.

Comment: Wortfindungsfragen sind auf ell.SE sehr häufig. Wenn die Syntax des Beispielsatzes beibehalten werden soll, wird hier nach einem passenden adjektiv für "hoher Standard" gesucht. Wenn "hoher Standard" attributiv in den Satz eingebaut werden soll, wäre die Frage nach einer Grammatik.die einer Konstruktion mit adjektiv vorzuziehen wäre. Mein Vorschlag "hohe Universitätsstandards". Die Frage sollte besser auf eine der Zielrichtungen ausgelegt werden. Dementsprechend angepasst und mit einer Erklärung versehen könnte die Frage dann wieder aufgemacht werden.

Comment: @vectory Danke schön

Comment: @Zich The problem with this question is that it's about the correct way to use a specific nominal ("hoher standard") within a very general grammatical context (_weil_ clause) when there is nothing about "hoher standard" that changes any of the rules that always apply.

Comment: @Zich e.g. the way the question is phrased now, I could give as an example "Ich gehe nicht in die Kneipe, weil ich einen hohen Standard habe", or "Ich gehe nicht in die Kneipe, weil meine hohen Standards das nicht zulassen", or any other way of using "hoher Standard", just in a _weil_ clause

Comment: @sgf I didn‘t know there is nothing special about `hoch standard` I was thinking a loaned collocation in a weil sentence would be different. Turns out it is not! People have asked much easier questions here and none of them has been put on hold or received down votes. I tried to paraphrase the question so it would not feel like proofreading or translation request but looks like some other unwritten rules regarding the question frame and type apply here which I am not aware of. It was my first time asking questions here and since I am still a stranger with those rules I won‘t try it again

Comment: Thanks everyone who invest time here, I would have deleted the question if I could, but I can‘t. And looks like the problem is with the context of question not the way it asks. So nothing else I can do to make it better. SO is becoming more and more unwelcoming these days and as an old member who already know how to ask question here. I really don‘t know what to do in this situation!

Comment: @Zich So then your question would be "Is there anything special about loaned collocations, e.g. _hoher standard_, in _weil_ sentences?" Note also that "Standard" is not an adjective, that might explain some of the downvotes.

Comment: @Zich And closing or downvoting is not determined by how easy the question is (nor should it be).

Comment: @sgf Yes your are right, standard is a noun however `hoch standard` is an adjective for sure. In addition `standard` could be used in a place of adjective which if I recall correctly it is called `noun as modifier`. This was the reason I’ve asked the question. Again thanks for your commitment and constructive comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to use a compound noun, that one must read *Hochstandarduniversitäten*, without spaces between the parts. Sounds terrible, as most compounds of loan words.

Instead, make *Universitäten* a posessive to *Deutschland* and explain *haben* with an accusative object:

> …, weil Deutschland**s** Universitäten **einen** hohe**n** Standard haben.

But this isn't too well either. It's because *der Standard* essentially means *bread+butter* in German, and *hoher Standard* is a loan expression itself. Better use something like that:

> …, weil Deutschland**s** Universitäten **ein hohes Niveau** haben.

Answer (score 2):

Es wäre stilistisch besser, »Deutschland« nur ein Mal zu verwenden. Beispiel:

> Ich möchte in Deutschland studieren, weil es dort erstklassige / hervorragende
>   Universitäten gibt.

Gegen den Gebrauch von »Standard« ist aus meiner Sicht nichts einzuwenden.

> Ich möchte in Deutschland studieren, weil die Universitäten dort einen hohen Standard haben.

Comment: Doch, ich finde schon, dass gegen *Standard* hier etwas auszusetzen ist: Das ist in dieser Verwendungsform eine Formulierung, die schnurstracks aus dem Amerikanischen kommt. Gutes (idiomatisches) Deutsch ist das nicht. Deine erste Übersetzung ist erstklassig. Aber *einen hohen Standard haben* kann man nur sagen, wenn man an seine Stilistik einen recht niedrigen Standard **ansetzt**.

Comment: PS: Noch schlimmer schnurstracks aus Amerika ist die Formulierung *auf einem anderen Level*, mit der die meist vermutlich jugendlichen Verwender in der Regel nichts anderes meinen als: *genial*, *ingeniös* oder - mit weniger Trara - *findig*. Aber Wort für Wort aus dem Amerikanischen zu übersetzen ist natürlich bequemer.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Und _»hoher Lebensstandard«_ wäre dann auch zu verwerfen?

Comment: Ich habe ja nicht gesagt, dass jegliche Verwendung des Wortes *Standard* schlecht ist. Aber *Die Universitäten in Deutschland haben einen hohen Standard* ist ein Amerikanismus. Ein nicht durch transatlantischen Medienkonsum verbogener Deutschsprecher würde das kaum sagen.